# Select Option from list Only once - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, select, laravel-5

In my controller:

```
public function putbillpage()
    {

      $proname = productmodel::select('itemname')->get();
        return view('putbillpage', compact('proname'));
    }
```

In My View:(It lists the product name)

```
<td>
    <select name="proname[]" class="form-control proname">
      <option value="" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Product</option>
           @foreach($proname as $v)
               <option value="{{$v->itemname}}" >{{$v->itemname}}</option>          
           @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
```

[image]

Whenever i click the plus on the right end a new row is added below.when is press cross row is removed.

Now my question is if i select a option in first row.then in the second row that option must not be displayed.[image].

in the above image in first row i have selected cricket bat and now in the second row only soaps must be displayed.And when i remove first row the cricket bat also must be displayed in the options.
Any Help or suggestions are most Welcome.Thanks.

Comment: You will have to put a check in there using Javascript.

Comment: I think I know the problem. You are directing to attach EVENT also on every cloning using jQuery by using + button. You can disable passing event to each clone method. Could you post the button click jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a Flag

for example Soap is already selected in the next row choice you should remove the Soap option or alert the user that this option is already selected

Just set a variable on your js or set a cookie for selected options

Let me know if this helps you Thank you